# Writing to /proc

Tags: linux-device-driver, scp, proc

I have an FPGA setup that is connected a folder within /proc.  I need to write to this file, but when I do this, the file size ends up being 0 and the file is not written, though no error is issued.  Oddly this behavior does not occur with scp.

- I can echo to file successfully:  echo -ne "\000\000\000\000" > /proc/file
- I can scp a file from a remote machine to /proc/file
- I cannot copy a local file to it:  cp localfile /proc/file
- sftp also gives a 0 file size

My question is: what is different between cp and scp and sftp, probably at a pretty low level, that one works and the others don't.

Comment: /proc nodes are not actual files, but file-like kernel interfaces, so it's unsurprising that reading one returns a size of 0 or unrelated to the written size.  As for why `cp` is failing that would depend on how the implementation does its work (you could examine the source or look with strace for example).  Pragmatically,  how about using cat with a redirect?

Comment: Hi Chris, oddly enough cat with redirect also doesn't work, though maybe I need to play around with it more.

Comment: How are you determining "doesn't work" ?  File size after the fact is probably not meaningful.

Comment: When my my FGPA uses the /proc file, it is using whatever was previously written using scp rather than anything newer written with sftp.